# Race around condition while reading N sheets of one excel workbook using different threads

Tags: java, excel, multithreading, jxl

There is an excel work book of 7 sheets each with 65000 records. I am using 7 worker threads to read each sheet in  parallel and process them thereafter with no write operation involved. For small file size(around 20 records in each sheet) the program works fine but for 400 thousand data, only 4-5 out of 7 threads return correct string array(readExcelSheet()) while for remaining 2-3 threads readExcelSheet() returns null. Is there any concurrency or race condition that I'm facing here ?

```
package com.btsl.multipleexcelread;

import com.btsl.xl.ExcelFileConstants;
import com.btsl.xl.ExcelRW;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
    public class OuterClass {

        String filePath=null;
        Workbook workbook = null;

    public processFile {
           filePath = Constants.getProperty("BATCH_FILE_PATH");
           processFileSheetWise(ExcelFileIDI.FILEID,true,filePath+File.separator+fileName);

    }


     public void processFileSheetWise(String p_excelID,boolean p_readLastSheet,String p_fileName) throws Exception
        {
            if(_logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                _logger.debug("processFileSheetWise"," p_excelID: "+p_excelID+" p_fileName: "+p_fileName);
            }
            final String METHOD_NAME = "processFileSheetWise";

            int noOfSheet = 0;
            try
            {       
                workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(p_fileName));
                noOfSheet=workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
                if(!p_readLastSheet) {
                    noOfSheet=noOfSheet-1;
                }

            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(7);             
            for(int i=0;i<noOfSheet;i++)
                {
                    executor.submit(new ProcessSheet(i));       
                }   
               executor.shutdown();
              while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
               }
               System.out.println("Finished all threads");

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                _logger.errorTrace(METHOD_NAME,e);
                _logger.error("processFileSheetWise"," Exception e: "+e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                try{if(workbook!=null) {
                    workbook.close();
                }}catch(Exception e){_logger.errorTrace(METHOD_NAME,e);}            
                workbook=null;
            }
        }


        private class ProcessSheet implements Runnable {
                  public ProcessSheet(int  index) {
                       this.sheetIndex = index;      
                  }
            public void run() {
                final String METHOD_NAME = "run";
              try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " sheet index = "+sheetIndex);
                    excelArr = readExcelSheet(ExcelFileIDI.BATCH_DIRECT_PAY_OUT,filePath+File.separator+fileName, sheetIndex);
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"excelArr length = "+excelArr.length);
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public String[][] readExcelSheet(String p_excelID,String p_fileName, int sheetIndext) throws Exception
            {
                String strArr[][] = null;
                Sheet excelsheet = null;
                try
                {
                    workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(p_fileName));  //should be global
                    excelsheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetIndext);    
                    int noOfRows = excelsheet.getRows();
                    int noOfcols = excelsheet.getColumns();
                    strArr = new String[noOfRows][noOfcols];
                    Cell cell = null;
                    String content = null;
                    String key=null;
                    int[] indexMapArray=new int[noOfcols]; 
                    String indexStr=null;
                    for(int col = 0; col < noOfcols; col++)
                    {
                        indexStr=null;
                        key=ExcelFileConstants.getReadProperty(p_excelID,String.valueOf(col));
                        if(key==null) {
                            key=String.valueOf(col);
                        }
                        indexStr=ExcelFileConstants.getReadProperty(p_excelID,String.valueOf(col));
                        if(indexStr==null) {
                            indexStr=String.valueOf(col);
                        }
                        indexMapArray[col]=Integer.parseInt(indexStr);
                        strArr[0][indexMapArray[col]] = key;                
                    }
                    for(int row = 1; row < noOfRows; row++)
                    {
                        for(int col = 0; col < noOfcols; col++)
                        {
                            cell = excelsheet.getCell(col,row);
                            content = cell.getContents();
                            strArr[row][indexMapArray[col]] = content;
                        }
                    }
                    return strArr;
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
                finally
                {
                    excelsheet=null;
                }
            }

    }

    `

    Thanks in advance.


    public class OuterClass {

        String filePath=null;
        Workbook workbook = null;

    public processFile {
           filePath = Constants.getProperty("BATCH_FILE_PATH");
           processFileSheetWise(ExcelFileIDI.FILEID,true,filePath+File.separator+fileName);

    }


     public void processFileSheetWise(String p_excelID,boolean p_readLastSheet,String p_fileName) throws Exception
        {
            if(_logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                _logger.debug("processFileSheetWise"," p_excelID: "+p_excelID+" p_fileName: "+p_fileName);
            }
            final String METHOD_NAME = "processFileSheetWise";

            int noOfSheet = 0;
            try
            {       
                workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(p_fileName));
                noOfSheet=workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
                if(!p_readLastSheet) {
                    noOfSheet=noOfSheet-1;
                }

            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(7);             
            for(int i=0;i<noOfSheet;i++)
                {
                    executor.submit(new ProcessSheet(i));       
                }   
               executor.shutdown();
              while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
               }
               System.out.println("Finished all threads");

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                _logger.errorTrace(METHOD_NAME,e);
                _logger.error("processFileSheetWise"," Exception e: "+e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                try{if(workbook!=null) {
                    workbook.close();
                }}catch(Exception e){_logger.errorTrace(METHOD_NAME,e);}            
                workbook=null;
            }
        }


        private class ProcessSheet implements Runnable {
                  public ProcessSheet(int  index) {
                       this.sheetIndex = index;      
                  }
            public void run() {
                final String METHOD_NAME = "run";
              try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " sheet index = "+sheetIndex);
                    excelArr = readExcelSheet(ExcelFileIDI.BATCH_DIRECT_PAY_OUT,filePath+File.separator+fileName, sheetIndex);
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"excelArr length = "+excelArr.length);
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public String[][] readExcelSheet(String p_excelID,String p_fileName, int sheetIndext) throws Exception
            {
                String strArr[][] = null;
                Sheet excelsheet = null;
                try
                {
                    workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(p_fileName));  //should be global
                    excelsheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetIndext);    
                    int noOfRows = excelsheet.getRows();
                    int noOfcols = excelsheet.getColumns();
                    strArr = new String[noOfRows][noOfcols];
                    Cell cell = null;
                    String content = null;
                    String key=null;
                    int[] indexMapArray=new int[noOfcols]; 
                    String indexStr=null;
                    for(int col = 0; col < noOfcols; col++)
                    {
                        indexStr=null;
                        key=ExcelFileConstants.getReadProperty(p_excelID,String.valueOf(col));
                        if(key==null) {
                            key=String.valueOf(col);
                        }
                        indexStr=ExcelFileConstants.getReadProperty(p_excelID,String.valueOf(col));
                        if(indexStr==null) {
                            indexStr=String.valueOf(col);
                        }
                        indexMapArray[col]=Integer.parseInt(indexStr);
                        strArr[0][indexMapArray[col]] = key;                
                    }
                    for(int row = 1; row < noOfRows; row++)
                    {
                        for(int col = 0; col < noOfcols; col++)
                        {
                            cell = excelsheet.getCell(col,row);
                            content = cell.getContents();
                            strArr[row][indexMapArray[col]] = content;
                        }
                    }
                    return strArr;
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
                finally
                {
                    excelsheet=null;
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: Might want to tag `c++` (guessing that's what it is)

Comment: Huh. Looks like Java to me. Definitely needs a tag (and you should probably also tag with whatever library you are using for reading Excel - POI?). Also, nobody outside of India is going to know what a lakh is.

Comment: Now, for a more productive comment, have you tried opening the file just once (one `Workbook` object), and passing an actual `Sheet` into `readExcelSheet()` instead of the filename and sheet index?

Comment: Thanks dcsohl for productive comment. I paassd the excel sheet to the constructor in run method but still I'm getting the problem :common.AssertionFailed
        at common.Assert.verify(Assert.java:37)
        at jxl.read.biff.SSTRecord.getString(SSTRecord.java:426)
        at jxl.read.biff.LabelSSTRecord.<init>(LabelSSTRecord.java:56)
        at jxl.read.biff.SheetReader.read(SheetReader.java:363)
        at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.readSheet(SheetImpl.java:650)
        at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getRows(SheetImpl.java:405)
        at readExcelSheet()